# Unable to use 'require' in downstream node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I am developing an express api, where routes are installed as a dependency of the main project. Inside the main project I have a config folder with index.js. index.js is exporting an object that serves as the route configuration.

Inside the main project, I am able to get inside this exported object from all of the files, however, when trying to require from this config object inside of the node_modules dependency, it is coming back as undefined. I have tried with both relative and absolute pathnames in the require statement and neither seem to retrieve the js object.

using commonJs. Confirmed that I am using module.exports and require statements on the receiving end. Tried require statement from app.js and include a module.exports statement there as well. No luck.

Is there some magical way to get objects exported from the main project into the dependency packages? Wondering if there is something simple I am missing.

```html
Structure:
-app.js (main)
-package.json
--routes (folder)
    |
    index.js ('imports' route express modules from node_modules)

--config (folder)
    |
    index.js (where module.exports.objectname = {stuff:stuff} exists)

--node_modules
    |
    packagefolder (project scope)
          |
          packagename (route scope)
          |
          functions (folder)
              bunchofjs files to complete i/o of requests
          routes (folder)
              index.js (package.json main. Handles require from ../../..)
          config (folder)
              index.js (where the config require statement is.)
```

Sample statement from main application in the config/index.js:

```html
const globalConfig = {
    port : 4443,
    otherinfo: "stuff"
}
module.exports.globalConfig = globalConfig
```

Sample code from inside node_modules/packagefolder/packagename/routes/index.js

```html
const port = require('../../../../../config').globalConfig.port
```

Sample error:

```html
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
```

The carrot( ^ ) symbol is on the dot between globalConfig and port.

Comment: Need of relative paths out of node_modules signs that you splitted your code wrongly. Dependency in your node_modules should be independent on your app else it is called circular dependency. For example, you can make function that accepts globalConfig and then import this function.

Comment: @bigless, could you clarify? Does this mean that the information object can only go in one direction? (destination never being inside a node modules package?)

Comment: If you push something to npm, it should link only other npm packages (in one direction) and it should be importable as a variable (not executed asap in global space).

Comment: I agree that i shouldn't. However, does that mean that I can't. i.e is it being blocked because it is against its intended use.

Comment: Actually I dont believe that package can require anything outside of node_modules because it would be serious vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Answer attributed from @bigless in comments. Having dependency packages reach outside of the node_modules folder would be considered a security risk and is blocked by design. The strategy of the app using configs needs to be redesigned to keep this in mind.